# Exm error "Could not fetch list of email clients"

Tags: exm

Sitecore.NET 8.2 update 7. EXM 3.5. We use custom smtp. This errors have no effects for sending. Could I off it?

```
Message: The request failed with HTTP status 403: Forbidden.
Source: System.Web.ServicesLog:at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.ReadResponse(SoapClientMessage message, WebResponse response, Stream responseStream, Boolean asyncCall)
       at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String methodName, Object[] parameters)
       at Sitecore.Modules.EmailCampaign.EmailPreviewService.EmailPreview.GetEmailClients(Credentials credentials)
       at EmailCampaign.Controls.EmailPreviewClientDataSource.EmailPreviewClientDataSource.GetEmailClients()

ERROR Could not fetch list of spam check clients
Exception: System.Net.WebException
Message: The request failed with HTTP status 403: Forbidden.
Source: System.Web.Services
       at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.ReadResponse(SoapClientMessage message, WebResponse response, Stream responseStream, Boolean asyncCall)
       at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String methodName, Object[] parameters)
       at Sitecore.Modules.EmailCampaign.SpamCheckService.SpamCheck.GetSpamClients(Credentials credentials)
       at EmailCampaign.Controls.SpamCheckClientDataSource.SpamCheckClientDataSource.GetSpamCheckClients()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can ignore those exceptions.

The email preview and spam check functionality has been deprecated.

> On February 28, 2018, Sitecore will turn off the Email Preview and
>   Spam Check services. The reason for this is that Litmus has decided to
>   deprecate their legacy API, which we currently use as a part of
>   Sitecore Email Experience Manager (EXM) Email Preview and Spam Check
>   services.
>
> Litmus is retiring their API in 2018 because they have a new product
>   offering. The new product does not allow an OEM integration, so it is
>   not a viable part of our partnership. Customers can utilize the new
>   service but must sign up with Litmus directly.

from [End of life for Email Preview and Spam Check (Litmus) services](https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/460210)